# ¿Como muestro los errores de linux (syslog) en PHP?

Tags: php, linux, línea-de-comandos

Este código se me está atravesando.

```
<?php   echo '<pre>';
        system('tail -f -n 5 /var/log/syslog');
        echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

Otros comandos puedo ejecutarlos bien pero este no me funciona.

¿Es posible con system abrir el archivo syslog y mostrarlo?

Comment: Te da algun error o algo?

Comment: No, no me da ningún error.

Comment: A ver prueba de esta manera: `system('journalctl -n 5 /var/log/syslog');`

Comment: Nada, tampoco me funciona. He entrado en la consola con *SSH* y me daba error de permisos, entonces con *sudo* delante si se ejecuta bien en la consola pero en *PHP* sigue sin mostrarlo.

Comment: Prueba a guardar tu comando en una variable y después haz un echo de ella--> `$prueba = system('tail -f -n 5 /var/log/syslog');` echo `$prueba;`

Comment: php es un lenguaje del lado del servidor por ende solo procesa y ejecuta no le puedes pedir que se quede esperando o leyendo archivos con `tail -f` si quieres que haga esto debes poner `tail -n 5` pero no puedes usar el flag `-f` ya que este flag hace que el comando quede a la espera de cambios o que se agrege data al archivo

Comment: @MarioGuiber guardándolo en una variable y mostrando la variable después tampoco funciona :(

Comment: @Bryro Pues quedaría así: **system('sudo tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog');** y tampoco funciona.

Comment: no puedes usar `sudo` :v ya que esperara a una `contrase;a` te recomiendo cambiar los permisos del archivo para que php puede leerlo sin problemas! con `chmod`

Comment: @Bryro por seguridad no quiero cambiar los permisos de es archivo.

Comment: @Ruiz86 Intenta esta forma: `echo exec('tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog');`

Comment: @Ruiz86 seguridad le querias dar a php permisos de `sudo` :v y el sys.log es un archivo de log del systema no almacena contra;as u otra cosa y solo debes darle permisos de lectura

Comment: @MarioGuiber tampoco :(

Comment: @Bryro ok, pues si es solo lectura si, acabo de probarlo y funciona bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Ruiz86 de nada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comenta @Bryro debes dar permisos al menos de lectura a ese archivo:

abre tu terminal y pon: `chmod 644 /var/log/syslog` después en tu `PHP` cambia tu código a: `system('tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog');`

**EDIT**

PD: No había leído los últimos comentarios. @Bryro publica tu respuesta y la votamos como positiva y cierro esta.